# SQL check the last transaction for each user where a transaction could be multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to write a stored procedure. One of the steps is to check each user last transaction and decide if it meets a certain condition. The condition is to check the last transaction and decide if it's what we call "Final Deposit".

I managed to solve it if the transaction is represented with only one row in my database.However, some user will have what we call ( a chained transaction ) as their last transaction which basically a transaction that is represented with 2 or 3 rows. If at least one of the chained transactions is Final Deposit then the whole transaction is considered Final Deposit in my report.

The logic I'm trying to have is like this :

```
  `foreach(user in users){
    IF (the last transaction is not chained) 
    THEN 
    check the last transaction if it's Final Deposit

    IF (the last transaction is chained AND with 2 rows/Transactions) 
     THEN  
     check the 2nd last transaction that belongs to this transaction if it's Final deposit

     IF(the last transaction is chained AND with 3 rows/Transactions ) 
     THEN 
     check if the 2nd or 3rd last transactions if one of them is final deposit
```

`

What I have done is having all the last transaction using the Row_number() function like this.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT T.terminal_id,
      US.register_id,
      U.[user_id],
      U.user_name,
      T.create_date,
      T.trans_type_id,
      T.bus_date_id,
      T.trans_config_id,
      TT.trans_type,
      TT.TRANS_TYPE_NAME,
      t.TRANS_NAME,
      t.TRANS_ID_CHAINED,
      Row_number() OVER (partition BY U.[user_id]
      ORDER BY T.create_date DESC) rank
      FROM [RCMDYNAMIC].[dbo].[transaction] T
      INNER JOIN [RCMDYNAMIC].[dbo].[usersession] US ON T.user_session_id = 
      US.user_session_id
      INNER JOIN [RCMSTATIC].[dbo].[user] U ON U.[user_id] = US.[user_id]
      INNER JOIN [RCMSTATIC].[dbo].[transactiontype] TT ON T.trans_type_id = 
      TT.trans_type_id
      INNER JOIN [RCMSTATIC].[dbo].[register] R ON US.register_id = 
      R.register_id
      WHERE TT.trans_level = 2) sub
   WHERE  sub.rn = 1 AND ( trans_type NOT IN ( 4, 6, 21, 23 ) OR deposit_option & 64 <> 64 )
```

From the results of this query I can tell if each user last transaction is NOT Final deposit and from there I continue my report logic. As I said before this only works when the last transaction is represented with only one row. I have no idea how to do it with the Chained Transactions (multiple rows for one transaction).

NOTE: the way to know if the transaction is chained or not is by the column (TRANS_ID_CHAINED). If it's 0 then it's not chained otherwise it will have the same id as the transaction it's chained with

something like this:

```
`User_ID   TRANS_TYPE  trans_config_id  TRANS_ID_CHAINED  Rank  
   1           4           7                 0             1
   1           10          7                 0             2
   2           22          64                12            1
   2           23          4                 12            2
   2           10          126               12            3
   2            4          7                 0             4
   3           10          3                 0             1
   4           6           64                13            1  
   4           10          7                 13            2 `
```

User 1 doesn't have a chained deposit (TRANS_ID_CHAINED is 0) so I can check only his Rank 1 transaction. User 2 have a chained transaction so I have to check his rank 2 and 3 transactions. User 4 also has a chained transaction I have to check his rank 2.

trans_config_id is a foreign key to the Configuration Table I use it to check if the transaction is configured to be Final Deposit or not.

I'm sorry for having a very long and not so clear question. I'M JUST STUCK FOR WEEKS WITH THIS PROBLEM!

:) Thank you

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server. Pick the correct one.

Comment: Don't be afraid to break each scenario out and UNION them all together.

Comment: @WEI_DBA sqlserver .

Comment: @Malk I thought of having 3 temporary tables. one for users with singular transactions, the other for users with 2 rows transactions, and the 3rd with users with 3 rows transactions. However, I don't know how to make SQL decide something like this "IF the TRANS_ID_CHAINED > 0 THEN count rows with the same TRANS_ID_CHAINED if  COUNT =2 then insert into 2 rows Table else insert into 3 rows Tables .After this I will have another issue which is check each row for each user.

Comment: @user3382285 which users from your example have this deposit? Is it user_id = 2 and user_id = 4?

Comment: @ЕвгенийКондратенко to know that I use trans_config_id to look up another value in table called "[depositconfig]" the numbers here were just random. What makes me know if they are final deopsit or not is this condition (trans_type NOT IN ( 4, 6, 21, 23 ) OR deposit_option & 64 <> 64)... 4 ,6 , 21 , 23 are IDs for transaction type (deposit) and then I check if they are final or not by this bitwise operation  deposit_option & 64 <> 64 (if  deposit_option & 64 = 64) it means it's deposit but not final. I'm sorry it's really confusing for me too.

Comment: I would suggest to simplify your query (this will help people understand the problem) in the question by removing all unnecessary tables and provide some sample data and desired output using http://www.sqlfiddle.com

Answer (score 0):

Is something like this useful to you? I'm not clear on all points above so I've left you some placeholders. I've chosen CTEs in this case but you might prefer temp tables.

Steps:

1. Get table above, call it sub.
2. Get all chained lines from sub with rank 1.
3. Left join to sub to bring back all lines from sub with either rank 1 or with a chain id matching a rank 1 line.
4. Get all rows from the result matching final deposit.

Example

```
WITH sub AS (
  [ code above to get table ]
), rank1 AS (
  SELECT User_ID, TRANS_ID_CHAINED
  FROM sub
  WHERE Rank = 1
    AND TRANS_ID_CHAINED <> 0
), last_tran AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM sub
  LEFT JOIN rank1
    ON sub.User_ID = rank1.User_ID
    AND sub.TRANS_ID_CHAINED = rank1.TRANS_ID_CHAINED
  WHERE sub.Rank = 1
    OR rank1.TRANS_ID_CHAINED is not null
)
SELECT *
FROM last_tran
WHERE [ Final Deposit ]
```